# Sharepoint authentication with Puppeteer and Node JS

Tags: node.js, authentication, sharepoint, puppeteer

I am having trouble finding a way to authenticate an user. 
When you start the Node JS Server manually this worked fine (and yeah its ugly code):

```
 if (data.URL.includes("https://share.url.com")) {
        await page.type('#userNameInput', 'user');
        await page.type('#passwordInput', 'pass');
        await page.click('#submitButton');

        await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
        await page.waitFor(6000);
    }
```

Sharepoint didnt know my user data so they navigated me to a login page where I could fill in the Login Information and then move to my requested site. But in the meantime there were 2 changed made: 1. This Login Page doesnt exist anymore, if the login information isnt found I just get linked to a page where it says "Sorry you don't have access to this page". The 2nd problem or change is that the node server is started by a service.

At the end I just need to somehow access the page and then take a screenshot of it. But the auth is making me trouble. I now need a workaround to this problem, but I cant think about other solutions.

**Puppeteer authenticate:**

```
await page.authenticate({
    username: "user", 
    password: "pass"
});
```

This doesnt work or using this with an auth header doesnt work either.

**Saving user cred. in browser (chrom(ium)):**

I tried to save the user cred. for the page inside the browser, but this didnt have any affect.

**URL Auth:**

I tried to auth inside the URL like (https://user:pass@share.url.com/bla/site.aspx) but it doesnt work.

I am out of ideas how to approach this problem, have you got any suggestions how I could try this in an other way or did you see errors in my code or in my thoughts?

Thanks go to Bill Gates

Comment: I want to add a few things: 1. I request a page like https://share.url.com/News/AllItems.aspx (url modified). Then I get navigated to an other page because I couldnt auth myself. Now I am on a page somewhat like https://adfs.url.com/adfs/ls/wia?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3asharepoint%3ashare&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fshare.url.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252FNews%252FAllItems%252Easpx&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fshare.url.com%2f_trust%2fdefault.aspx. On this page in firefox a promt opens, which wants me to auth me with username & pass. After manually login everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

About

> Saving user cred. in browser (chrom(ium)):

I had similar situation - I wanted to do screenshot from facebook when I'm logged in. To achieve it I did steps like:

1) Created temp user data dir

```
mkdir /tmp/puppeteer_test
```

2) Run Chrome with these arguments

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/puppeteer_test --password-store=basic
```

3) Go to facebook.com, log into and then close the browser

4) Run puppeteer with appropriate arguments:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
  args: ['--user-data-dir=/tmp/puppeteer_test']
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://facebook.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
await page.screenshot({path: 'facebook.png'});
await browser.close();
```

Comment: You brought me on the correct solution. I think my problem is very specific, but I had to disable Cookies in the Chromium and startup Puppeteer using the User Agent String of Firefox => args: [ "--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0'"]. After that the Single Sign On of the Company didnt work anymore but I got redirected to the Login Page of our Sharepoint (which I usually with SSO enabled didnt get to). Now I can insert my Login Cred. and access SharePoint. Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am doing following for SharePoint

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});

// Open SharePoint page
console.log("Opening page");
await page.goto('https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite');
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
console.log("Page opened");

// Input username
console.log("Inputting username");
await page.type('#i0116', 'user@mytenant.com');
await page.click('#idSIButton9');
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
console.log("Username input completed");

// Input password
console.log("Inputting password");
await page.type('#i0118', 'password123');
await page.click('#idSIButton9');
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
console.log("Password input completed");

// Stay signed in
console.log("staying signed in");
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
console.log("staying signed in completed");

// Wait, because rendering is picky
await page.waitFor(6000);
```